# Set up KVM host with multiple VLANs, each attached to "its own" external IP address

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge

I'm trying (and having a hard time) to setup a clean KVM environment with: an Ubuntu (20.04) host (with a single NIC), multiple ubuntu KVM guests, 2 public IPs, and one Vlan per IP.
Basically something looking like:
[image: ideal structure]

---

My needs are:

- I have 2 public IP addresses attached to my host NIC
- I want 2 VLANs for my guests and no communication between machines on different VLANs
- Each VLANs attached to one public IP
- All guests having at least access to internet, but not necessarily being accessible from outside ("one way", classic NAT?)
- Some guest acting as deamons/servers, being accessible from the internet ("two way", port redirection?)
- The host should still be able to access internet
- Ever having only 2 (one per IP) mac addresses advertised outside my host (to my provider's router)

---

I didn't find any online resources about how to achieve this architecture and none of my attempts

have yet been successful.
I think I can achieve it with the right combination of bridge and (NAT) VLAN but some of my research indicated that I might need routing with Iptables.

---

**Is it possible to achieve this structure and, if yes, how?**

- for the host network config (neptlan ,ifup, iptable, etc)
- and the libvirt config (virsh xml)

---

**edit:**
To make my needs more clear:

```
Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to X.X.X.X on port 443 must be forwarded to VM1 in VLAN-1
Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to X.X.X.X on port 5432 must be forwarded to VM2 in VLAN-1
Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to Y.Y.Y.Y on port 443 must be forwarded to VM3 in VLAN-2
Traffic from VM1 in VLAN2 destined to 0.0.0.0/0 on any port must be routed through Y.Y.Y.Y ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your scenario, I assume the following:

```
Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to X.X.X.X on port 443 must be forwarded to VM1 in VLAN-1
Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to X.X.X.X on port 5432 must be forwarded to VM2 in VLAN-1
Traffic from 0.0.0./0 destined to Y.Y.Y.Y on port 443 must be forwarded to VM3 in VLAN-2
```

If my assumption is correct, I would suggest using iptables. In this case, you will to perform port-forwarding.
From the KVM host machine, do the following:

```
$ sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d X.X.X.X --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.1:443 #(VM1 in VLAN1)
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d X.X.X.X --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2:5432 #(VM2 in VLAN1)
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d Y.Y.Y.Y --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.3:5432 #(VM3 in VLAN2)
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT #(Allow retrun traffic)
```

Comment: I'm sorry my schema and my needs were unclear (I updated them to be more accurate). Actually what i'm looking for is: 

Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to X.X.X.X on port 443 must be forwarded to VM1 in VLAN-1

Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to X.X.X.X on port 5432 must be forwarded to VM2 in VLAN-1

Traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 destined to Y.Y.Y.Y on port 443 must be forwarded to VM3 in VLAN-2

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your needs. Please check